# Swift firebase database child issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm mid way through a video series from 2016 where we build a message app. Up to episode 11.

Right now the function `handleSend` covers the `FirebaseDatabase` entry of the message and a few other bits of data stored under `messages`. This code alone works fine and the entries entered. What I'm trying to do now is make a reference to each message using the `afromId` in a new child node called `user-messages` to sort out which messages to display to the user and which to filter out. I don't quite really understand what is happening but I will eventually.

Right now my issue is I have typed out the code exactly as displayed in the video but it will not enter anything into the database under `user-messages`. The `toId`,`fromId`,`timestamp` and actual message data enters correctly however. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Do you think it might be because the code is old?

Here is my code:

```
    @objc func handleSend() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
    let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
    let toId = user!.id!
     let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let timestamp = (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
    let values = ["text": inputTextField.text!, "toId": toId, "fromId": fromId, "timestamp": timestamp] as [String : Any]
    
    childRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        
        let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(fromId)
        
        let messageId = childRef.key
        userMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])
    }
}
```

and here is the code from [YouTube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3P0J.jpg)

Comment: Check the log output of your app for error message, specifically something around "permission denied". If that is in there, you don't have permission to write to the database, and should check out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+permission_denied

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your comment and edit. I checked my permissions and both "read" & "write" are set to true. 
I had success with changing 
`userMessagesRef.updateChildValues([messageId: 1])` 
to
 `let values1 = ["messageId": "1"] as [String : Any]
   userMessagesRef.updateChildValues(values1)` 

It took me hours to play around with the code until this worked.

Comment: Though the reference is now being saved as a String. I hope that won't cause me problems later on. Onwards to more learning!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working Tim. I might be worth posting as a self-answer, and accepting that, just in case someone stumbles into it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The troubled code was from a 2016 version of Xcode.
Through trial and error I replaced the troubled code with:
`let values1 = ["messageId": "1"] as [String : Any] userMessagesRef.updateChildValues(values1)`

The reference is now a string however. But I am working around that.